# SQL Atualizando Valor errado

Tags: sql, query, phpmyadmin, sql-update, mariadb

Estou criando uma QUERY para alterar todos os dias das datas registradas no BD para o ultimo dia do mês daquele registro... o que acontece é que quando eu jogo a QUERY selecionando um registro no mes 5 (maio) ele atualiza o valor do dia com 30...

segue o codigo:

```
UPDATE CPSCli 
SET FimValidPre = 
CASE MONTH(FimValidPre)
    WHEN (1 OR 3 OR 5 OR 7 OR 8 OR 10 OR 12) THEN
        DATE_FORMAT(FimValidPre, '%Y-%m-31')
    WHEN (2) THEN
        DATE_FORMAT(FimValidPre,CONCAT('%Y-%m-',IF(YEAR(FimValidPre) % 4 = 0,29,28)))
    ELSE
        DATE_FORMAT(FimValidPre, '%Y-%m-30')
    END
```

Comment: Defina: "ele da pau!". É necessário adicionar a mensagem de erro obtida para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: desculpe... corrigi agora! vou redefinir a pergunta...

Comment: você poderia dar um exemplo de dado da sua tabela para a gente simular aqui ;)

Comment: desculpe, não entendi... qual é a diferença do DATE_FORMAT do ELSE? por que no caso ele está executando o ELSE, uma vez que a data do registro estava 4 e foi atualizado para 30!

Comment: Responda sua pergunta com a sua solução, é bem melhor que a resposta estar na pergunta, certo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVIDO!**

Resolvi de uma maneira bem mais simples do que a que postei!

segue o resultado:

```
UPDATE CPSCli set FimValidPre = LAST_DAY(FimValidPre)
```

LAST_DAY retorna o ultimo dia do mês com a data completa em formato SQL da data do argumento passado a ele!

Answer (score 3):

Execute a seguinte query:

```
UPDATE CPSCli
   SET FimValidPre = DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, FimValidPre) + 1, 0))
```

Explicando o funcionamento da query:

```
DATEDIFF(m, 0, FimValidPre)
```

**DATEDIFF**: Estamos pegando por meio do parâmetro **m** (datepart que representa meses), o número de meses a partir de **1900 (último ano de pesquisa aceito no SQL)** até a nossa data **FimValidPre**. Então se por exemplo a nossa data for **03/08/2018** será retornado **1423**.

```
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, FimValidPre) + 1, 0)
```

**DATEADD**: Essa função tem a função de somar datas, porém estamos dizendo para somar usando como referência os meses **(por causa do mm como parâmetro)**. No segundo parâmetro estamos passando o resultado da função **DATEDIFF** que é **1423**. Estamos somando **+1** para buscar o próximo mês após nosso mês atual do campo **FimValidPre (que no nosso exemplo é a data 03/08/2018)** então nosso mês atual é **08 - Agosto** e o próximo seria **09 - Setembro**. O último parâmetro estamos utilizando para pegar o primeiro dia do próximo mês, que seria **01/09/2018**.

```
DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, FimValidPre) + 1, 0))
```

**DATEADD**: Com o resultado que possuímos **01/09/2018 00:00:00.000**, estamos passando como parâmetro os segundos **s**, e dizemos para subtrair um segundo **-1** desse nosso resultado. A partir desse entendimento, iremos obter o resultado esperado que é o último dia do mês às 23:59:59 horas **2018-08-31 23:59:59.000**.

Caso precise filtrar por algum critério específico, não se esqueça de adicionar a cláusula **WHERE** na query.

Comment: A solução provavelmente funcionará, mas seria legal também incluir uma explicação sobre a `query` para que o AP entenda a solução e não apenas replique-a.

Comment: Obrigado @Pedro Paulo... vou estudar sua Query para entendê-la... no entanto resolvi de outra forma... vou postar na pergunta!